# Show that the set of all inner points of a set like $A$ ( a subset of real numbers) is open.

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:
We have to show that if $x$ is an inner point for A then it is an inner point of inner points of $A$.
There exists some  positive $r$ for which the interval 
$(x-r, x+r)$ is in $A$.

hint:we know that $(x-r, x+r)$ is an open set.

How should I continue?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since $(x-r,x+r)$ is open, what do we know by definition is the case for every point within $(x-r,x+r)$?

Comment: we know that for any point like y  within it there exists some r which  (y-r, y+r) is in (x-r, x+r)

Comment: Exactly, so every point of $(x-r,x+r)$ is an interior point of $(x-r,x+r)$, but $(x-r,x+r)\subset A$, so every point is also an interior point of...